# Is there a way to refactor this code?

Tags: ruby

is there any way to refactor this code?

```
def my_method
  response = HTTParty.post 'http://www.url.com', { 
    body: {
      param1: "value1",
      param2: "value2"
      }
    }
  response.message.include?("OK") ? true : false
end
```

I'd like to check if the response message includes okay but without needing to define the response as a variable. Is there any way I can retrieve the current method reply from the previous step in the method?

Comment: Why exactly can't you define the response as a variable ?

Answer (score 9):

```
HTTParty.post('http://www.url.com', { 
  body: {
    param1: "value1",
    param2: "value2"
  }
}).message.include?("OK")
```

Please note, that `? true : false` is also redundant.

Answer (score 1):

```
def my_method
  HTTParty.post('http://www.url.com', { 
    body: {
      param1: "value1",
      param2: "value2"
      }
    }).message.include?("OK")
end
```

Comment: You are calling `message` on `Hash` instance.

Comment: True. I have been too quick.

Comment: Well, we have the same answer after that correction :p

Comment: Sure. I lost few seconds by waiting for a potential answer to my comment ^^

Comment: Fair enough. I need an option “split upvotes with the neighbour.”